# arduino class with map

Tags: visual-studio-2010, arduino

I have created a project inside Visual Studio with Visual Micro. Can't figure out this issue. I have this TestClass.h file

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include "Arduino.h"

class TestClass
{
private:
    std::map<unsigned,unsigned> umm;
    std::map<int,int> mmm;
public:
    TestClass(void);
    ~TestClass(void);
};
```

This code gives the following errors:

```
> Compiling 'testPrj' for 'Arduino Uno' TestClass.cpp : In file included
> from TestClass.h : ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'map' with no type
> TestClass.h : ' TestClass.h : expected ';' before '<' token
> TestClass.h : ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'map' with no type
> TestClass.h : ' TestClass.h : expected ';' before '<' token Error
> compiling
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might start here: http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11119

Comment: It seems like the compiler can't find the definition of the `std::map` class. Can you create a simple .cpp that tries to instantiate a single instance of `std::map`?

Comment: You should look into the overhead created by using templates. I enjoyed reading through this: (.pdf warning!) http://www.iar.com/Global/Resources/Seminars/The%20Inefficiency%20of%20Cplusplus,%20Fact%20or%20Fiction.pdf Arduino is not meant to handle stuff like this.

Comment: @Derek. No, I can't instatiate a instance of map. Oh, and nice pdf.

Comment: Are you trying to use an Arduino port of STL?

Comment: @Derek: I was trying to use visual studio's STL library. I thought it will work. I am interested in using stl with arduino. I have found this https://github.com/vancegroup/stlport-avr/tree/STLport-5.2-arduino-installed

Comment: @CPJ I have had luck with the STL port found here: https://github.com/maniacbug/StandardCplusplus

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino by default does not support the STL so you cannot use STL data structures.

As tzerb points out. There is an implementation of the STL for the AVR ([Installation directions](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11119)). I have not used it so I can't tell you if it is any good.